# how to greate a multiaple sheets (google sheet)?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

i wana duplicate a sheet with protected ranges and i use this code, but i need to copy this sheet multiaple times by range.

```
    function copy(){

  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss = sh.getSheetByName("Support Sheet");
  const prot = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
  
  let nSheet = ss.copyTo(sh).setName("Year Data");
  let p;
  
  for (let i in prot){
    p = nSheet.getRange(prot[i].getRange().getA1Notation()).protect();
    p.removeEditors(p.getEditors());
    if (p.canDomainEdit()) {
      p.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `but i need to copy this sheet multiaple times by range.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: this code for copy tabs with ProtectionType , i need to copy tabs multiaple time by range

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from `this code for copy tabs with ProtectionType , i need to copy tabs multiaple time by range`, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.